# react native android: How to save state on screen rotation or orientation

Tags: android, android-activity, react-native

On rotating screen, it seems activity is getting restarted, it loses all its state. I checked android developer guide.[Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). It has mention about how to handle screen orientation and using `onSaveInstanceState()` before it destroys your activity and restore the state during `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering to my question this is how it worked for me, if anyone is facing same problem, then edit your AndroidManifest.xml on 
***android/app/src/main*** and
    ***local-cli/generator-android/templates/src/app/src/main***

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for process death, if you put the app in background and the system kills it, how will you restore it?

Comment: Note that using `android:configChanges` should be used only as a last resort and it is generally considered as a bad practice in native Android community.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is to avoid restarting the app on orientation change without saving the state and saving the state is not really required if you follow this.

```html
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ||
  newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ||
  newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED ) { 
    return; 
  }
```

**Explaination:-**

When you rotate the screen app will get restarted here is the reason why and how you can avoid restarting of the app on orientation change,

1. You have to add `android:configChanges="orientation"` in AndroidMenifest.xml `<activity>` tag, what it will do is it will tell android to call `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`.
2. Override `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` in your activity file in my case it was MainActivity.java, in React Native it is by default overridden, and inside this method `instanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground(newConfig)` is getting called this method is responsible to restart your app, now to avoid restart behaviour you have add condition depending on newConfig

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed explanation of how to save/retrieve activity instance in Android

https://web.archive.org/web/20160308105435/http://www.intertech.com/blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the link, appreciate it. I was seeking an advice on the context of react native android. The scenario is when routed from scene A to scene B, it works perfectly but on screen rotation it lose it data and return to an initial scene A, it does not stay on current scene B. Basically, I want to know how to create native module in react native. eg: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content

Answer (score 0):

We've worked around this in our hybrid React Native <> Native Android app, which needs to have orientation changes enabled, by caching a reference to the React Native view in the ViewModel, and reusing that when the view is recreated after runtime changes.

This is not recommended by Android and leads to a few other issues around the view having stale references, but those have been worked around successfully.